# Canvas inside canvas of html5

Tags: html, canvas

Can we place a canvas inside the existing canvas?If we can,please help to do it in html5.

Comment: Please provide more details as to what you are actually trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There are two possible ways to interpret your question.  One is that you mean to actually nest `canvas` elements themselves, like this:

```
<canvas id="outer">
    <canvas id="inner"></canvas>
</canvas>
```

This is legal (according to [validator.nu](http://validator.nu/)) but pointless.  The content inside the `canvas` element is for fallback.  The only way the content inside the `canvas` element gets used is if the browser doesn't support `canvas`, in which case the inner `canvas` element won't be seen anyway.

The other possible way to interpret your question is can you display the image shown on one canvas within another.  This is quite straightforward, a `canvas` element can be used as the first parameter to `context.drawImage()`.  If you have two `canvas` elements:

```
<canvas id="c1" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
<canvas id="c2" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
```

Then [this script (using jQuery)](http://jsfiddle.net/robertc/mGbFS/) will draw on the first `canvas` and then add that four times as an image to the second `canvas`:

```
var c1 = $('#c1');
var ctx1 = c1[0].getContext('2d');

ctx1.fillRect(50,50,100,100);

var c2 = $('#c2');
var ctx2 = c2[0].getContext('2d');

ctx2.drawImage(c1[0],0,0,100,100);
ctx2.drawImage(c1[0],100,0,100,100);
ctx2.drawImage(c1[0],0,100,100,100);
ctx2.drawImage(c1[0],100,100,100,100);
```

But again, why would you?  You can replicate the image of the second `canvas` above [just using one](http://jsfiddle.net/robertc/szX4f/):

```
var c1 = $('#c1');
var ctx1 = c1[0].getContext('2d');

ctx1.fillRect(25,25,50,50);
ctx1.fillRect(125,25,50,50);
ctx1.fillRect(25,125,50,50);
ctx1.fillRect(125,125,50,50);
```

So in summary: yes, it's possible, but it's not really necessary in simple use.

Comment: There are plenty of (admittedly non-trivial) reasons for using a second canvas. For example, drawing a moving graph is easiest done by copying the graph to another offscreen canvas, clearing the main canvas, and then copying the offscreen canvas back offset to the left by one pixel and drawing the new data in the missing column. (This is necessary only if the background of the graph is transparent.)

Comment: @Phrogz Yes, also various image processing things.  But I stand by my "it's not really necessary in simple use", I don't think any of that stuff is relevant to this question or this answer.

Comment: Perhaps not, but a newcomer might take your wording to mean that it's excessive, when it's often the neater and more optimal way to accomplish something. If you have a changing canvas with static elements (say, a game), there are massive performance benefits to this technique - you need only draw the bitmap/vectors into a canvas once, then simply draw this onto the main one when updating. +1 for good answer though.

Comment: It may be used in the case when printing labels or photographs. Like the outer canvas holds multiple similar type of inner canvas inside. The inner canvas contains text or photo. Try createPattern() function of canvas for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

It would be absolutely pointless to nest a canvas inside of another canvas. The page only sees what is inside the `canvas` tag if the browser doesn't support the `canvas`. So, just do what robertc said:


    `<canvas id="background">fallbacks/polyfills go in here...</canvas>
    <canvas id="foreground">.. or here, but not other canvases.</canvas>`