# Can you put one canvas inside another canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas, easeljs

basically, i have 2 javascripts(easelJS with add scripting) that run on 2 different canvas elements in my html index file.

i was wonder, if i can sort of "wrap" those two inside a main canvas element, and thus have more power to play with their layout opposed to one another, rather than relying on html/css positioning.

Is it possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure if this answers your question, but yeah: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11625767/canvas-inside-canvas-of-html5

Answer (score 1):

Nesting `canvas` inside another `canvas` is possible. Say something like this:

```
<canvas id="outer">
    <canvas id="inner"></canvas>
</canvas>
```

Not sure if this answers your question, but you can refer [Canvas inside canvas of html5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11625767/canvas-inside-canvas-of-html5) for more information.